# Downloading empty file when accessing to subdirectory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have trouble with setting default file for subdirectory.
 http://d2770ni5llmjzr.cloudfront.net/songinfo/index.html  works properly, but  http://d2770ni5llmjzr.cloudfront.net/songinfo ends up with downloading blank file.

I already set static domain of my bucket as origin of distribution.

Following is log of curl -v http://d2770ni5llmjzr.cloudfront.net/songinfo

```
*   Trying 13.225.105.93...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to d2770ni5llmjzr.cloudfront.net (13.225.105.93) port 80 (#0)
> GET /songinfo HTTP/1.1
> Host: d2770ni5llmjzr.cloudfront.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> 


HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily 
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
 Content-Length: 313 < Connection: keep-alive 
 x-amz-error-code: Found 
 x-amz-error-message: Resource Found 
 Location: /songinfo/ 
 Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2019 20:21:42 GMT
 Server: AmazonS3 
 Age: 9262 
 X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront 
 Via: 1.1 2f061b9f7c9e6f3de68229cddaa32e46.cloudfront.net (CloudFront) 
 X-Amz-Cf-Pop: ICN54-C1 
 X-Amz-Cf-Id: KgKM9xl5ggcwOWvoUng9rWiVE12UI0q0oPvCUJ2IvJxmyPlJtvmMRg== 

<html> <head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head> <body> <h1>302 Moved Temporarily</h1> <ul> <li>Code: Found</li> <li>Message: Resource Found</li> <li>RequestId: 454F29ADAC061274</li> <li>HostId: FsYd6DZeb9nuWA/wQazkp+doZmsriSoakDrcsyQy7jkFQFw/y8ngKW0lR1yT1sYprBJ6CtjK3KU=</li> </ul> <hr/> </body> </html>
    * Connection #0 to host d2770ni5llmjzr.cloudfront.net left intact
```

Comment: You need to have s3 website endpoint as an origin to cloudfront instead of rest api endpoint if you want that.

Comment: I already set s3 endpoind as an origin to cloudfront. But I still have same problem

Comment: s3 website endpoint , like bucketname-s3-website.region.amazonaws.com https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: I think setting of cloudfront took some time to be applied. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Web files named index (ex. index.html, index.php) are the default files for their directory. The index.html file loaded automatically on safari, chrome, and firefox for me.

Comment: Does it mean you loaded index.html with http://d2770ni5llmjzr.cloudfront.net/songinfo ? I am just downloading empty file.

Answer (score 0):

```
>HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
>Location: /songinfo/
```

This is an HTTP redirect, and it is exactly what S3 is supposed to do when you ask for a "directory" that will serve an index document, but you don't supply the trailing slash in the request.

Your site is working correctly, but curl doesn't follow these redirects by default.  You need to tell it to, with the `--location` (long form) or `-L` (short form) option.

```
curl -v -L https://...
```

You should then find that curl does what you expect.

Comment: I think it took some time to apply my setting. Thank you for your help!